# Does "show how" mean repeat, or just show?

Tags: meaning-in-context

In the dictionary, *how* has meanings of *the manner or way in which* and *to what extent, degree*.

> By the end of the lesson, only Hermione Granger had made any difference to her match; Professor McGonagall **showed the class how** it had gone all silver and pointy and gave Hermione a rare smile.

Did Professor McGonagall repeat what Hermione did (demonstrate how she did it), or did she just pick up the match that Hermione had changed, to show how much it had been changed?

AND

Can you *show me how* I may tell which of these meanings is in play?

Comment: The fact that I assumed Prof McGonagall was a man probably means I shouldn't presume to know this! My guess is that *in this specific case*, "how" could be replaced by "that" or "how much". But that's only because it's the most likely scenario, not because of the grammatical form. In other very similar constructions, "how" could be replaced by something like "the way it was done". In short, this particular use of the word "how" is inherently ambiguous.

Comment: So, grammatically, how - as a conjunction - can't include the meaning of 'how much or the degree of what have been done'?

Comment: All that need be done here is to replace "how" with "that". This is a simple substitution and it is what works here. The "how" here is not at all ambiguous: "how" = "that". No question. The Prof did not repeat what Hermoine did, she merely held up the match and displayed Hermoine's successful result.

Comment: @Bill Franke: I disagree there's "no ambiguity". In these half-a-dozen instances of ["showed him how it had"](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22showed+him+how+it+had%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1), unquestionably in some you can substitute *"[the fact] that"*, but in others it's *"the extent to which"*, or *"the method by  which"*. You cannot determine which applies by grammar alone, and in some cases I'm sure the construction could be ambiguous. I think the closevoters are wrong, and this question should be reopened.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: I'm not saying that in other instances there's no ambiguity, only in the OP's instance. It's Harry Potter. The Profs don't repeat their students' successful magic, they merely showcase the work. The sentence and its interpretation have nothing to do with grammar but everything to do with knowing the Harry Potter books. I've read most of them and seen almost all the movies. That's why I know (1) there's no ambiguity and (2) what this particular sentence means.

Comment: @Bill Franke: I don't really understand that position. I haven't read much Harry Potter (when I tidied up OP's original text, I referred to the Prof as "he"!). But the *title* of the question shows [how?!] he's asking about *this type of construction in general*. Knowing about and using "external" factors to interpret *this specific example* seems to me a bit of a cop-out, and not what we usually do here on ELU. But I won't keep on, since apparently you yourself didn't closevote.

Comment: @BillFranke I agree with FumbleFingers that there is an ambiguity here, and I have edited the question to make it more clearly Real.

Comment: @StoneyB: Why do you think that there's an ambiguity in that particular sentence? **If** you've read most of the Harry Potter Books and seen most of the movies, **then** it's quite clear that **for that particular sentence only**, there is **no ambiguity**. If you haven't, then it's ambiguous. This is an example of a specific word having a specific meaning **in context** -- but you have to know the context before you can understand the meaning of the word. Sam's answer is the right one.

Comment: In this case, the context is all the classroom scenes in all Harry Potter books.

Comment: @BillFranke  If you want to close as Too Localised, that's one thing; but NARQ? And *must* you know all that context, or is it possible to resolve the ambiguity within the context provided by OP? It was closed as NARQ because it could not be reasonably answered in its then form; its form is now different.

Comment: @StoneyB: I don't understand all the reasons for closing. It seems to me a real question. Yes, you must know enough about the story to understand the Q & the meaning of "how" in this case. As Sam says, they all know **how** she did it: using a magic spell available to everyone, but she'd practiced it better. That's part of the context--it's magic, not science, logic, or math. Throughout the story, Harry uses spells & fails because he's not practiced enough. Maybe the Q's too localized. The 2nd S doesn't help me understand the 1st. No, the OP's context of 1 S isn't enough, but book 1 is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second one.  They all know how she did it.  The remarkable things was the fact she *could* do it.

Comment: All students did their own job, so they couldn't know how she did it.

Comment: The teacher gave them all the information they needed to perform the spell. She didn't keep anything secret. It's just practicing it that takes time. Think of it like juggling. I know how people juggle 4 balls, I just can't do it myself.

Comment: The fact that *you* know how she did it (having read all about it in the book), and the possibility that *they* know (having been taught by same teacher) isn't all that relevant. The question is ***how** do you know* what the words mean if you don't already know that before you read them?

Comment: @FumbleFingers I suppose you don't technically know which meaning, except through experience, and the thought that if the authors intention was the first meaning, it could and should have been written in a much less ambiguous way.

Comment: If we can ‘change’ how into ‘that,’ would it be a very matter-of-fact interpretation?
http://education.yahoo.com/reference/dictionary/entry/how
CONJUNCTION:
1. The manner or way in which: forgot how it was done.
2. That.
3. In whatever way or manner; however: Cook it how you please.

Comment: @Sam: My point exactly. I don't disagree with your interpretation, obviously. If we treat OP's question as solely about the meaning of his *specific sentence*, that's all there is to it. But unquestionably, in [With her hand she showed him how it had been jammed against the wall](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=Xz5KAAAAMAAJ&q=%22showed+him+how+it+had%22&dq=%22showed+him+how+it+had%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=L6KnUMPpBeaw0QWH1ICACg&ved=0CDwQ6AEwBA), to "show how" means "show the method whereby", not "show the fact that".